# I want to use only Left and Right in borderPane (java)

Tags: java

I want to show the time of two different countries at one screen. I have a clock made with borderpane that can show the time of a city. I want to show two of them with another borderpane by

```
this.setLeft(clock1);
this.setRight(clock2);
```

However, the borderpane requires 5 regions : top, bottom, center, left, right
I want only two regions, left and right. I want the screen to be full with only left and right, no blank in other regions. Also same size of left and right.

Is there any class with only left and right?
OR, in borderPane, is there any way to resize three regions(top,center,bottom) as 0?

Comment: What UI framework are you using?

Comment: I am using javaFX